# Showing Twice Differentiability by Computing Hessian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, hessian-matrix

As in the question title, if I can show that the hessian matrix of a function $f$ exists and is well-defined, by computing it can I then conclude that the function $f$ is twice differentiable?

For example, given an $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\boldsymbol x\mapsto (\frac{1}{x})^{1/\alpha}$ for some $\boldsymbol x\in \mathbb{R}^N$, $\alpha>4$ where all components of $\boldsymbol x$ are bigger than $0$. Then I must show that $f$ is twice differentiable over $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: What is your definition of "twice-differentiable" when talking about functions of several variables?

Comment: I have updated my question with an example.

Comment: 1. By $\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/\alpha}$ do you mean $\left( \frac{1}{|x|}\right)^{1/\alpha}$? 2. I still don't know what you mean *exactly* by "twice-differentiable". Do you just understand it to mean "all second partials exist and are continuous" or do you mean something slightly different?

Comment: It would probably be useful to know what you mean by «show the hessian exists and is well defined».

Comment: @John, 1) Yes. 2) By twice differentiability I understand it to mean all seconds partials exists and are continuous, indeed.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, by showing that the hessian exists and is well-defined I mean that we can compute the hessian without, for instance, getting $y/0$ or any other invalid expressions.

Comment: Take any continuous function of a single varible which has a derivative at all points but whose derivative is not continuous, and consider it primitive $f$. Then $f$ has a continuous derivative and at each point that derivative has a derivative, but the function $f''$ is not continous. Therefore $f$ has a Hessian a each point (here this means: has a second derivative at each point) but $f$ is not twice differentiable.